# Operating System Development Short Cut

Tags: c, ubuntu, operating-system

I wanted to try my hand at making an OS however I don't really want to do all the hardware interfaces so I was thinking if it was possible to get the core from ubuntu or another linux distro with all the hardware driver interfaces and to build it from there. I really want to start where I can simply printf to the screen in c to create a console like interface or open a grapical interface with openGl or simple pixel buffer for systems without hardware acceleration without regard to hardware.
Sounds kinda cheaty but I think it could work with a little bit of work. It there anywhere I can look for a core like this, I don't need the UNIX part just the interface to the drivers and a kernal to start my code.

Thank you for any information you can shed onto the situation.

Comment: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drivers make out the biggest part of an operating system, so what you want to write probably is not an OS.
From what you say it rather sounds like you'd like to have an OS without any predefined graphical interface. This can be easily archieved by using Linux alone.

Note: linux is an operating system which the "distros" extend by adding lots of programs and configurations. The colorful login screens and desktop environments like Unity, Gnome or KDE are only a bunch of programs, configured to autostart as soon as the system is booted. Take those away and you have one single black'n'white terminal with a shell in it and no windows, icons, menus or pointer.

That said you could try two things: **Arch Linux** (https://www.archlinux.org/) which is a full fledged linux distribution that comes with no desktop environment by default. If you install Arch and start your computer you'll be presented a text login and a shell, no desktop at all. The good thing about this is that you can install any programs (e.g. desktop) any time if you wanted to since Arch comes with a really nice command line package manager and repositories. Without installing any extras this is a good way to learn how to write low-level code that runs on the command line and you'll learn a whole bunch of how to set up Linux too. The Arch Linux wiki is full of very well written guides from geeks for geeks. If you want a full-fledged system that runs just fine with no desktop, this is the way. This might be too easy for you, though.

The second thing is **Linux From Scratch** (http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/). This is an extensive guide on how to build your own minimal Linux from scratch (who would've guessed…). Here you're way more low-level and you have full control over everything. But since you want to make your own OS the short way this might be the way to go. There's no package managing system and only vanilla code here. The funny thing about LSF is that you can change the Linux source, recompile it and tinker around with everything without having to care about any side effects like common linux services or certain programs not working anymore.